# Two power supplies in one machine

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, cable

I have two hard disks which I would like to use. When I bought the second one I didn't realize that my power supply only had one hard disk cable.

Is there any way I can still use my second one, like a connector or something? If not, I have a newer one (900W) that I haven't used, but a friend said that it's too powerful for the use of my computer and might cause some damage.

Any solutions?

- **Mainboard** : Asus P5LD2-SE
- **Processor** : Intel Pentium D 945 @ 3400 MHz
- **Video Card** : NVIDIA GeForce 7300 GT
- **Hard Disk** : ST3250820AS (250GB)
- **Physical Memory** : 1536 MB
- **Monitor Type** : Samsung SyncMaster - 17 inches
- **Network Card** : RTL8168/8111 PCIe Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
- **DVD-ROM Drive** : TSSTcorp CD/DVDW TS-H652D ATA Device
- **Operating System** : Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: One thing though: PSUs shutdown automatically when they sense an under-voltage condition; normally under 10% of the rated amount. So unless your components use only 30 watts, it's highly unlikely.

Comment: Im not much of a computer guy,but i edited my original post with my spec will u please look at it and tell me what u think? thx

Comment: Yeah, get a [Y cable](http://www.cyberguys.com/product-details/?productid=321).  It'll cost you maybe $2.95 at your local computer parts store, or half that online.

Comment: (Note: Before you get a Y cable, make sure it's the right type, based on the connector sizes.  There are big and small connectors.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Motherboards can't be damaged by having a "too strong" power supply, the PSU only delivers the energy that your components draw.

A 900W rating means that's the maximum that this particular PSU can deliver, but if your components have a combined draw of 300W, that's all they get.

For using one power cable for two disks, you may use what's called `Internal Power Supply Cable Splitter` or `Power Supply Y Cable` from your local electronics shop. However, ensure that your PSU is up to the task.

[image]

Comment: i see.. what about the cable part? so does that mean that i have to change my psu?

Comment: @winterwindz: See above.

Comment: thank you for the info,but heres the thing,im using a 350W PSU, im using some pretty old stuff and it has extra power cables so i assume it can take it.im not sure. however if it does work what about the sata cable?the L looking head cable?
PS: im gnna edit and put my spec up. thx

Comment: 350W power supply is potentially borderline (depends on what else is going on inside the PC).  If you add the hard drive and get strange behavior all of a sudden (like strange video issues, or crashes), you might have exceeded the limits of your power supply.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much impossible to damage the computer with an over-wattage PSU, but it could be inefficient. Most power supplies run at different efficiencies depending on load. Depending on how your 900W PSU is designed, it could be VERY inefficient, seeing as a 350W seems to be working right now.

Don't worry about damaging the computer, though. Every computer PSU is regulated to well within acceptable voltage, regardless of load.

Answer (score 0):

No.  If you go to various sites like Cyberguys or Newegg, you should be able to get a power supply splitter cable.